# JBoss ActiveMQ Topic RedeliveryDelay too small

Tags: java, jboss, jms, activemq-classic

I use JBoss with the default ActiveMQ to send messages to some clients which have subscribed to a topic. Unfortunately `onMessage(Message message)` gets called multiple times for just one message.

JNDI-Lookup:

```
private static void lookupRemoteTopic() throws NamingException, JMSException
{
    final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
    final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "jms/topic/refresh";
    final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "ejb";
    final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "ejbSuperSecret";
    final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
    final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://192.168.2.72:8080";

    final Properties env = new Properties();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, DEFAULT_USERNAME);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    InitialContext namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

    // Perform the JNDI lookups
    TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
    Topic destination = (Topic) namingContext.lookup(DEFAULT_DESTINATION);

    TopicConnection con = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection(DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);        
    con.start();
    TopicSession session = con.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    TopicSubscriber sub = session.createSubscriber(destination);
    sub.setMessageListener(this);
}
```

onMessage:

```
public void onMessage(Message message)
{
    try
    {
        // Do some stuff with it
    }
    catch (JMSException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Message sender:

```
@Inject
private JMSContext context;
@Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/topic/refresh")
private Destination topic;

MapMessage mesg = context.createMapMessage();
// set message body
context.createProducer().send(topic, mesg);
```

After one message has been send, the clients get bombarded with messages, although `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` is set.

How can I slow the sender down?

If an SSCCE is needed, I can provide one, it is just a lot to include (server, client, configuration, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broker is doing it's job which is to deliver messages to your client as fast as it can.  If your client can't handle that then there are other tools like Apache Camel which provide [Throttler](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html) type components which you can use to insert in between the client and broker to slow down the incoming messages.  ActiveMQ supports [embedded Camel routes](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-embed-a-broker-inside-a-connection.html) so you could set this up on the broker.

If you want maximum control of the rate that messages are processed in your application then you should switch to the synchronous consumer model and call receive on your consumer only when you are ready to process a new message.

Comment: I don't mind the speed, it's just the thing that `onMessage` gets called multiple times for only one message. Isn't that what `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` is supposed to do, so that the message gets acknowledged and can be deleted from the server? How can I set a delay between the redeliveries?

Comment: You can't as I said, the broker delivers message as fast as it can.  If you are receiving the same message again then you might want to check your producers to see if they are duplicating their sends etc.  Hard to say given the minimal information